# How can I Create a Dragable Object or Control in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios4, drag-and-drop, uibutton, uilabel

I was developing a iPhone application in which some value has been written down on UILable or UIButton. I want to ask that how can i drag these control to another location.

Please provide me some example of iPhone for this.

Can it is possible to drag these control into UITableView and then save UITableView values ??

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this logically.

Think you have an table view at particular co-ordinates in view. and you have a label with some text then you can move that label by using Touch Delegate methods.

> touchesMoved

and the use

> touchesEnd

for you logic,here you can save that label text in your data source array from where you display the table content and use [YourTabl reloadData]; and Finish that label presence.

I think it makes sense.

Comment: but how can i get that which label is drag to the UITableView because there are several labels and user will choose one of them and then he will drag it to the UITableView. Your tutorial is not doing this functionality. Please provide some another example.

Comment: Bro example is not for any thing on table, Example shows how you can use touches.For that what you want you need implement my thought in code,i am giving you a concept nothing else.And for finding the label you need a tag added to that level or IBOutlet for that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can drag any UIView. Just change the center of your view in

`- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`